# How to insert a value that contains an apostrophe (single quote) in postgresql from java insert?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have data coming from html contact form which i am sending in a email through a java webservice. Everything is working fine but when user inserts data containing  apostrophe (single quote) insert fails.
Pls help me to understand How and where to handle this data.
TIA

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use **[Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)**,it will escape special characters and avoid **[SQL_injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Prepared Statements, and you can just escape all special characters like single quote, double quote etc. before inserting in the database.

Comment: Double quotes don't need escaping

Comment: if you have string like ' The "Sun" is Big. '. Then you need to escape that double quotes to insert the full string.

Comment: No, absolutely not.  http://rextester.com/FMNMZ90697 The **only** character that needs escaping in a SQL string constant is the single quote `'`. Nothing else